# How do I select all the column headers from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/poep7xee/3/)

this is where I am at:

```
$('#mytable thead tr').each(function(index) {
        //console.log($(this).html())    
    console.log(index)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).html()` gets all the column headers.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/poep7xee/4/)

```
$('#mytable thead tr th').each(function(index) {
        console.log($(this).html())    
    console.log(index)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Headers` are stored in `th`, so you need to go one level deeper.

```
$('#mytable thead tr th').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).html())    
});
```

[***Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/poep7xee/5/)